# where is (m-d) < m derived from in this proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

> So far it looks good. But in the following process of the proof. "(m-d) < m", as underlined in red, appears out of the blue. I don't know from where it's derived. Can you find where is (m-d) < m computed from, or the line mentioning (m-d) < m above the red underline?

[image]

Source
http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/shirley/a325k/Handouts/induction%20and%20wop/q-r-theorem-proof.pdf

Comment: If you a subtract (positive) $d$ from $m$ you make it smaller.

Comment: Have you tried proving it yourself? Usually proofs skip details if the writer believes that the reader should be able to prove it themselves without too much difficulty.

Comment: @SeanEnglish Yes I tried, but didn't complete the proof by myself.

Comment: m -d < m for positive d is pretty basic.  Did you step back and think about what this means.  m < m + d if d is positive; m - d < m if d is positive, etc...  I can't really put this in the category of "skipped detail". re @SeanEnglish

Comment: @fleablood I agree with you, but to a new mathematician it may seem like a skipped detail. Since this proof is usually presented in a proofs course or a first course in modern algebra, anything that isn't spelled out directly with reasons could be considered a "skipped detail" to someone new to proofs.

Comment: @fleablood I think I was recalling d>0($d \in Z$) and m≥0. But so many variables were mentioned that I couldn't pick out two variable d, m , which should have been dealed with to get that.

Comment: Well, it's a damned if you do, damned if you don't situation.  Reading through at a brief clip, suddenly seeing $m-d < k$ would raise a flag so $m-d < m$ looks like an unverified assumption.  Until you actually think about it and realize it's trivial.  It's happened to me countless times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding $d-m$ to both sides. That tells you that $m-d<m\iff 0<d$

Since $d$ is in fact positive, $m-d<m$.

In intuitive terms, if you subtract a positive number, you get smaller.

Answer (score 2):

It's stated that $d > 0$.

So $m + d > m + 0 =m$

So $m + d -d > m -d$

So $m > m -d$.